# Aligning texts inside a wrap flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

My goal is to have this UI with full width: [App with full width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhJde.png) and in the minimum width [App with the minimum width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZH1K.png)

My problem is that i cant have both working because when i have the app with the full width working, I get this error after resizing the app to the minimum width: [Error after resizing to the minimum width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCRnB.png)

Here is the code with the full with working, but not the mininum width:

```
`@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Column(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              resumoConteudoQuebrado(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Column resumoConteudoQuebrado() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Wrap(
            children: [
              Wrap(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Perguntas respondidas: ${questionario.getPerguntasRespondidas()}/${questionario.getTotalPerguntas()}",
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Pontuação ${questionario.getPontuacaoTotal()} - ${questionario.getAvaliacao()}",
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            butaoSubmeter(),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
      ],
    );
  }`
```

But if I try to solve it i get this when i resize the app to the full width: [Error after resizing to the full width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWQ5J.png)

Here is the code with the mininum with working, but not the full width:

```
`//the build widget remains the same
  Column resumoConteudoQuebrado() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Wrap(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Perguntas respondidas: ${questionario.getPerguntasRespondidas()}/${questionario.getTotalPerguntas()}",
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Pontuação ${questionario.getPontuacaoTotal()} - ${questionario.getAvaliacao()}",
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            butaoSubmeter(),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
      ],
    );
  }`
```

I've tried to use expandeds/flexibles it is not working the way i intended it to be. I've also used ifs and widths to set rules, but my app is suposed to run in both mobile/windows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) widget in Flutter to dynamically change the layout based on the parent size and add triple dots (`...`) when text overflows, you can use the following example:

```dart
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  if (constraints.maxWidth < 600) {
    return Wrap(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      children: [
        Text(
          "foo",
          style: TextStyle(
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "foo",
          style: TextStyle(
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  } else {
    return Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        Text(
          "foo",
          style: TextStyle(
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "foo",
          style: TextStyle(
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
})
```

In this example, the `TextOverflow.ellipsis` property is applied to the `TextStyle` of each `Text` widget. This ensures that if the text overflows the available space, it will be truncated with three dots (`...`). The decision to use either a vertical or horizontal `Wrap` is based on the `constraints.maxWidth` value provided by the `LayoutBuilder`. If the maximum width is less than 600, a vertical `Wrap` is used, otherwise, a horizontal `Wrap` is used.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i forgot to say in the post but i've used ifs and setted rules with ifs, but my app is suposed to run both on mobile/windows

Comment: increase maxLines to 2-3, and TextOverflow property avoid the overflow error.